# How do I output a JSON object with underscore.js?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using the underscore.js template library with my backbone example. My template looks like this:

```
<script id="results-template" type="text/template">
    <h2><%= title %></h2>
</script>
```

The JSON object looks like this:

```
{"src":"placeholder.jpg","title":"an image placeholder","coordinates":[0,0],"tags":["untagged"],"location":"home"}
```

I am trying to parse this object through my template but the error I get through my console is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? Live fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/amit_e/muLjV/46/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your problem is this:

```
JSON.stringify(myPhoto)
```

this needs to be

```
myPhoto.toJSON()
```

reason: your `JSON.stringify()` will put the whole myPhoto model as a json **string**. now, Backbone has this function to output json as a **json object**, so you can use `model.toJSON()`

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/muLjV/50/

Comment: dahh!! I confused the two JSON functions. So you are saying `myPhoto.toJSON()` is passing the object along to the template but the `stringify` function won't?

Comment: i'm saying, that myPhoto.toJSON() returns a json object, while JSON.stringify returns a string.  check this jsfiddle to see the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/muLjV/55/ (keep in mind to check the console, it has no output in the results window)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only title, it is not required to process whole JSON of Photo model. You can just retrieve the single property.

Below Render will suffice the need here.

```
render: function(event){
  var yourOutput={title:myPhoto.get('title')};
  var compiled_template = _.template( $("#results-template").html(),yourOutput);
    this.el.html(compiled_template);        
}
```

Your current JSON object is as below. It is not much complex, you can get any of title, src,coordinates,tags, location without effort.

```
{
    "src": "placeholder.jpg",
    "title": "an image placeholder",
    "coordinates": [0,0],
    "tags": ["untagged"],
    "location": "home"
}
```

Comment: did not know you could evaluate an expression in the middle of an json document. will that `{title:myPhoto.get('title')}` work?

Comment: Answered above! you can get any of title,src,coordinates,tags, location with code similar to above. You find JSON method efficient. You can use it :)